# Safari transitioning width and position, does not recalculate

Tags: html, css

If I move and enlarge an element using top, right, transform and width in safari it does not move smoothly on the first transition. It will transition based on the old width I assume then once it has finish it repositions the element. However transitioning back it works fine.

It's probably easier to understand by viewing it:

https://codepen.io/miketricking/pen/zZJZLR

```
<section class="container">

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="card">
  <h3>click here</h3>
 </div>
</div>

</section>


.container { 
  width: 550px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: teal;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease;
 }

#wrapper.center {
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
 }

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}


h3 {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

I'm really lost on this one. I can see the problem just have no idea on how to solve it.

Comment: Try this fiddle and let me know: https://jsfiddle.net/c6txtr8n/

Comment: Note, the same code from the above fiddle will not work smooth in codepen, so I guess they have som issue, which I filed as a bug report

Comment: @LGSon The fiddle has the same problem in safari. The transition seems fine in other browser in both codepen and fiddle